# Append var in JavaScript to input value

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
var swal = json.Event[i].SwURL;
$("#swurl").append("value='"+ swal +"'");
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to make the `swal` become the value in the form that I have. However it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="swurl"
       type="text" value="" name="event[swlink]">
```

This is the html:

**Edit**

Due to the nature of this potentially being a duplicate.

I've attempted this method

```
$("#swurl").val(swal);
```

However this hasn't worked.

Also I'm wondering if its because the javascript_tag is taking a while to load, Therefore not being inserted into the simple form.

Hers the simple form field if anyone was wondering

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :swlink %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.text_field :swlink, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control", id: "swurl" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add markup too

Comment: Boss, you need to edit the question to make it not a duplicate. I know it is not.

Comment: Hello Sam, try this code `$("#swurl").val(swal);` and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @samroberts See, it depends. The issue is not with the code you have. The issue is with a big thing in the back. The `simple_forms` is screwing you up... So... Write the right problem description.

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#swurl").attr('value',swal);
$("#swurl").val(swal);
```

Should both work

Comment: Not `.attr("value='"+ swal +"'");`, but `.attr("value", swal);`

Answer (score -3):

What Praveen is providing is correct. But if you want particularly 'value' attribute to change. You can use below:

```
$("#swurl").attr('Value',swal);
```

Hope this will work for you.